# Would the energy of a planet orbiting a star be conserved assuming that the only acting force is the star's force of gravity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, astrophysics

We know from Kepler's first law that the orbit of a planet is elliptical. We also know that the time period swept by the planet is less as it comes to its closest distance from the star, the "perihelion" compared to that when it is at its farthest distance from the star, at the "aphelion".

To make it clear, since v = dr/dt, and dt is more at the aphelion, less at the perihelion.
An increase in dt would decrease v since they're inversely proportional.

$k = 1/2mv^2$

$U = - GMm/r$

$Etot = K + U$.

$Etot = 1/2mv^2 - GMm/r$

Does the U's r, increase at the aphelion to substitute for the decrease in K's v?

That's the only possible way of thinking of it since r and v are the only "non-constants" that could flex to conserve energy.

Note: Assume that there's no friction or any external forces but Gravity's.

Correct me if anything is wrong. Got my info from a physics lecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total energy in an elliptical orbit, involving two bodies, is constant and given by
$$ E_{\rm tot} =-G\frac{m_1m_2}{2a}\ ,$$
where $a$ is the semi-major axis and $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the two masses involved.

Since in a general elliptical orbit, the separation between the two objects varies, then so does the gravitational potential energy. In order to keep the total energy constant, the kinetic energy changes accordingly.

Gravity is a conservative force and does no net work around a closed orbit and the energy of any isolated system is conserved.

Comment: Would this mean that the radius will increase if the time period did in order to conserve energy, keeping the constant energy, equal?

Comment: @MarkusMaximus how do you change the orbital period without doing work on the system? The orbital semi-major axis and orbital period are directly linked through Kepler's third law. You cannot change one (by doing work) without changing the other. That is not a conservative process and the total energy would change.

Comment: Changing the radius would affect the period over which an object orbits taking into account that the total orbital energy is conserved. Larger orbital period = Larger orbital distance(radius) since the increased period is a result of that increased radius.

Comment: @MarkusMaximus The formula for the total energy is given in my answer. You cannot change the orbital radius and conserve orbital energy. Kepler's third law is *not* $P \propto a$.